# how to display files from ftwebrequest not in html format

Tags: c#

Using ftpwebrequest to list all the files in a directory but they are coming back in html format it seems, is there any way I can just get the filenames one per line without the timestamp and all the other stuff?

Here's some code

```
    StreamWriter fileout = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test\output4.txt");
    FtpWebRequest ftp;
    string addr = "ftp://blah/";
    string usr = "foo";
    string pwd = "bar";
    ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(addr));
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usr, pwd);

    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    fileout.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

    fileout.WriteLine("Directory List Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);
```

I just tried printWorkingDirectory instead of listDirectory and didn't work either

sure I'll add some output btw I just tried using ftpstream and got the exact same thing.

```
    FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(@"C:\test\output6.txt", FileMode.Create);

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();
    Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    long cl = response.ContentLength;
    int bufferSize = 2048;
    int readCount;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    while (readCount > 0)
    {

        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    ftpStream.Close();
    outputStream.Close();
    response.Close();
```

finally output

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>FTP Listing of /point/download/archive/ at indexftp.barcap.com</TITLE>
<BASE HREF="ftp://foo:bar@indexftp.blah.com/test">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H2>FTP Listing of /point/download/archive/ at indexftp.barcap.com</H2>
<HR>
<A HREF="../">Parent Directory</A><BR>
<PRE>
Jul 29 2013 10:00       147280 <A HREF="foo1.csv">foo1.csv</A>
Jul 30 2013 10:04       147079 <A HREF="foo2.csv">foo2.csv</A>
Jul 31 2013 10:05       146935 <A HREF="foo3.csv">foo3.csv</A>
</PRE>
<HR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

where foo1, foo2, foo3 are sitting on the ftp and I only want the output

```
foo1.csv
foo2.csv
foo3.csv
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what you're getting back to your question?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8833793/56778

Comment: wow that worked thanks a lot!  what a time saver